# Код C, работа с сокетами (forward data)

Tags: c, сокет, proxy, epoll

Привет всем. Есть вопрос, который мне крайне непонятен... Пишу систему балансировки нагрузки и вот, сервер, который должен перенаправлять данные от клиента к целевому серверу и обратно первые несколько раз делает это корректно, но спустя некоторое время, когда я из браузера выполняю запрос на свой сервер, то получаю ошибку (events[i].events & EPOLLERR). Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. Код ниже

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <sys/epoll.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    /*
     * Клиент может подключаться к любому сетевому адаптеру,
     * который есть на машине, на которой работает данный сервер
    */

    #define MAXEVENTS 500000
    //for conf file
    #define MAX_CONFIG_VARIABLE_LEN 20
    #define CONFIG_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE 100
    #define MAX_IP_SERVER_LEN 256
    #define BUFLEN 16384

    #define CLIENT_SOCKET_ERROR -5
    #define CLIENT_RESOLVE_ERROR -6
    #define CLIENT_CONNECT_ERROR -7
    #define TRUE        1
    #define EPOLL_QUEUE_LEN 256

    void forward_data(int source_sock, int destination_sock);
    static int forwardData (int fd);


    int forwardSockets[EPOLL_QUEUE_LEN];
    int internalSockets[EPOLL_QUEUE_LEN];

    struct timeval read_timeout; //Таймаут для чтения

    char in_buf[255]; //Буфер для хранения ответов сервера - балансировщика
    unsigned char out_buf_1[255]; //То, что отправляем серверу, который хранит значения заггруженносчт серверов фермы
    char buf_for_serv_ferm[BUFLEN];
    char buf_for_client_from_server_ferm[BUFLEN];

    char *remote_host;

    int clientSocket;
    int servFermSocket;
    int dataForClientSocket;
    int remote_sock;
    int client_sock;
    int forwardSD;

    int error_write;
    int error_read;
    int error_close_socket;

    //strcmp - сравнение строк
    char char_ip_addr[20];
    char char_cpu_load[5];
    char char_mem_load[5];

    int int_cpu_load;
    int int_mem_load;
    int int_cpu_mem_load;

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr; //Удаленный сервер балансировщик (для получения ip свободного сервера)
    struct sockaddr_in localaddr; // Эта машина

    struct sockaddr_in nodeServerAddr;

    struct sockaddr_in for_browser_client;

    int int_index_0, int_index_1, int_index_2, int_index_3; //Для хранения индексов элементов массива
    char *index_0, *index_1, *index_2, *index_3; //Для адресов, с которых начинать или которыми заканчивать (для парсинга пришедшего массива)

    //---------------------------------------------------------Читаем конфиг---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    char server_ip[20];
    char client_ip[20];
    int server_port;
    int client_port;


    void read_config_file(char* config_filename) {
        FILE *fp;
        char conf_buf[CONFIG_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE];

        if ((fp=fopen(config_filename, "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open config file %s", config_filename);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        while(!feof(fp)) {
            if(fgets(conf_buf, CONFIG_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE, fp)==NULL) printf("\n");
            if (conf_buf[0] == '#' || strlen(conf_buf) < 4) {
                continue;
            }
            if (strstr(conf_buf, "SERVER_IP ")) {
                char prm_name_1[MAX_CONFIG_VARIABLE_LEN];
                sscanf(conf_buf, "%s %s\n", prm_name_1, server_ip); //IP сервера - балансировщика
            }
            if (strstr(conf_buf, "SERVER_PORT ")) {
                char prm_name_2[MAX_CONFIG_VARIABLE_LEN];
                sscanf(conf_buf, "%s %d\n", prm_name_2, &server_port); //port сервера - балансировщика
            }
            if (strstr(conf_buf, "CLIENT_IP ")) {
                char prm_name_3[MAX_CONFIG_VARIABLE_LEN];
                sscanf(conf_buf, "%s %s\n", prm_name_3, client_ip);
            }
            if (strstr(conf_buf, "CLIENT_PORT ")) {
                char prm_name_4[MAX_CONFIG_VARIABLE_LEN];
                sscanf(conf_buf, "%s %d\n", prm_name_4, &client_port);
            }
        }

        printf("SERVER_IP = %s\n", server_ip);
        printf("SERVER_PORT = %d\n", server_port);
        printf("CLIENT_IP = %s\n", client_ip);
        printf("CLIENT_PORT = %d\n", client_port);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    static int
    make_socket_non_blocking (int sfd)
    {
      int flags, s;

      flags = fcntl (sfd, F_GETFL, 0);
      if (flags == -1)
        {
          perror ("fcntl");
          return -1;
        }

      flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
      s = fcntl (sfd, F_SETFL, flags);
      if (s == -1)
        {
          perror ("fcntl");
          return -1;
        }

      return 0;
    }

    static int
    create_and_bind (char *port)
    {
      struct addrinfo hints;
      struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
      int s, sfd;

      memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (struct addrinfo));
      hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     /* Return IPv4 and IPv6 choices */
      hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* We want a TCP socket */
      hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     /* All interfaces */

      s = getaddrinfo (NULL, port, &hints, &result);
      if (s != 0)
        {
          fprintf (stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror (s));
          return -1;
        }

      for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
        {
          sfd = socket (rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
          if (sfd == -1)
            continue;

          s = bind (sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
          if (s == 0)
            {
              /* We managed to bind successfully! */
              break;
            }

          close (sfd);
        }

      if (rp == NULL)
        {
          fprintf (stderr, "Could not bind\n");
          return -1;
        }

      freeaddrinfo (result);

      return sfd;
    }

    int
    main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int sfd, s;
      int efd;
      struct epoll_event event;
      struct epoll_event *events;

      struct  sockaddr_in server_fwd;
      struct  hostent *hp;

      read_config_file("config.conf"); //Чтение конфигурационного файла

      //Сокет клиента (эта машина)
      localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client_ip);
      localaddr.sin_port = client_port;

      //Сервер - блансировщи
      serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      serverAddr.sin_port = htons(server_port);
      serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);

      if (argc != 2)
        {
          fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [port]\n", argv[0]);
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

      sfd = create_and_bind (argv[1]);
      if (sfd == -1)
        abort ();

      s = make_socket_non_blocking (sfd);
      if (s == -1)
        abort ();

      s = listen (sfd, SOMAXCONN);
      if (s == -1)
        {
          perror ("listen");
          abort ();
        }

      efd = epoll_create1 (0); //создаёт структуру данных, с которой в дальнейшем идёт работа
      if (efd == -1)
        {
          perror ("epoll_create");
          abort ();
        }

      event.data.fd = sfd;
      event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
      s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &event); //Добавление файлового дескриптора к наблюдению
      if (s == -1)
        {
          perror ("epoll_ctl");
          abort ();
        }

      /* Buffer where events are returned */
      events = calloc (MAXEVENTS, sizeof event);

      /* The event loop */
      while (1)
        {
          int n, i;

          n = epoll_wait (efd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
          for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
              //int infd;

              /*if((events[i].events & EPOLLERR))
              {printf("(events[i].events & EPOLLERR)\n");continue;}
              else if(events[i].events & EPOLLHUP)
              {printf("events[i].events & EPOLLHUP)\n");continue;}
              else if(!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN))
              {printf("!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)\n");continue;}*/

              //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) ||
                  (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) ||
                  (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)))
            {
                  // An error has occured on this fd, or the socket is not
                  //   ready for reading (why were we notified then?)
              fprintf (stderr, "epoll error\n");
              close (events[i].data.fd);
              continue;
            }
             //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          if (sfd == events[i].data.fd) // Готов слушающий дескриптор (sfd)
            {
              printf("1 ------------- sfd = %d\n 1 ------------------- events[i].data.fd = %d\n", sfd, events[i].data.fd);
                  /* We have a notification on the listening socket, which
                     means one or more incoming connections. */
                  //while (1)
                    //{
                      struct sockaddr in_addr;
                      socklen_t in_len;
                      int infd;
                      char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];

                      in_len = sizeof in_addr;
                      infd = accept (sfd, &in_addr, &in_len); //Дескриптор подключившегося клиента
                      if (infd == -1)
                        {
                          if ((errno == EAGAIN) ||
                              (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))
                            {
                              /* We have processed all incoming
                                 connections. */
                              break;
                            }
                          else
                            {
                              perror ("accept");
                              break;
                            }
                        }

                      s = getnameinfo (&in_addr, in_len, //in_addr - адрес клиента
                                       hbuf, sizeof hbuf,
                                       sbuf, sizeof sbuf,
                                       NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
                      if (s == 0)
                        {
                          printf("Accepted connection on descriptor %d "
                                 "(host=%s, port=%s)\n", infd, hbuf, sbuf);
                        }

                      /* Make the incoming socket non-blocking and add it to the
                         list of fds to monitor. */
                      //Добавление клиентского дескриптора в массив ожидания
                      s = make_socket_non_blocking (infd);
                      if (s == -1)
                        abort ();

                      event.data.fd = infd;
                      event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                      s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &event);
                      if (s == -1)
                        {
                          perror ("epoll_ctl");
                          abort ();
                        }
                    //}
                  //Клиентский дескриптор готов




                      //--------------------------------------------Получаем IP наименее загруженного сервера фермы---------------------------
                      //Посмотреть к кому можно приконнектится (запрос на load balansing server)
                      //clientSocket =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //Для получения IP свободного сервера
                      clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

                      if (connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)  {
                              printf("ERROR connecting");
                              exit(1);
                          }
                      make_socket_non_blocking(clientSocket);
                      //int flags = fcntl(clientSocket, F_GETFL, 0);
                      //fcntl(clientSocket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);


                      //bind(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&localaddr, sizeof(localaddr));
                      //memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);
                      //memset(localaddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof localaddr.sin_zero);

                      //socklen_t addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
                      //connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

                      memset(out_buf_1, 0, sizeof(out_buf_1));
                      memset(in_buf, 0 , sizeof(in_buf));

                      sprintf(out_buf_1, "%s\n", "wget");

                      //error_write = sendto(clientSocket, out_buf_1, (sizeof(out_buf_1)), 0,
                      //                             (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)); //Отправка данных на сервер - балансировщик

                      error_write = write(clientSocket, out_buf_1, strlen(out_buf_1));

                      //printf("%s", buf);
                      if (error_write < 0)
                      {
                         printf("*** ERROR - sendto() failed \n");
                         exit(-1);
                      }

                      //Устанавливаем таймаут на чтение (если данные за это время не прочитаны, то хз)
                      //read_timeout.tv_sec = 0;
                      //read_timeout.tv_usec = 10;
                      //setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &read_timeout, sizeof read_timeout); //Приваиваем флаги таймаута сокету

                      error_read = 0;
                      //Читаем данные из сокета (получаем ip наименее загруженного сервера)
                      //int serverAddrLen = sizeof(serverAddr);
                      while (error_read <= 0)
                      {
                         error_read = read(clientSocket, in_buf, sizeof(in_buf));
                         //sleep(1);     //Спим 1 секунду
                         printf(".");
                         //fflush(stdout);
                      }
                      //error_write = write(clientSocket, out_buf_1, sizeof(out_buf_1));
                      //error_read = read(clientSocket, in_buf, sizeof in_buf);

                      error_close_socket = close(clientSocket);
                      if (error_close_socket < 0)
                        {
                          printf("*** ERROR - close() failed \n");
                          exit(-1);
                        }
                      //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                      //-----------------------------------------Отправляем данные клиента на сервер фермы-------------------------------------
                      remote_host = in_buf;

                      printf("Trying to create forward socket\n");
                      if ((forwardSD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
                          perror("Cannot create forward socket.");
                          exit(1);
                      }

                      printf("Binding...\n");
                      bzero((char *)&server_fwd, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
                      server_fwd.sin_family = AF_INET;
                      server_fwd.sin_port = htons(80);
                      //host = "192.168.0.10";
                      if ((hp = gethostbyname(remote_host)) == NULL) {
                          printf("Failed to get host name");
                      }
                      bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&server_fwd.sin_addr, hp->h_length);

                      printf("Connecting to interal machine.\n");
                      printf("Server Forward Port: %d\n", ntohs(server_fwd.sin_port));
                      printf("Server Forward IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(server_fwd.sin_addr));

                      // Connecting to interal machine
                      if (connect (forwardSD, (struct sockaddr *)&server_fwd, sizeof(server_fwd)) == -1) {
                          perror("connect failed");
                          exit(1);
                      }

                      // Add the new socket descriptor to the epoll loop
                      event.data.fd = forwardSD;
                      if (epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, forwardSD, &event) == -1) //epoll_fd = efd
                      {
                          printf ("epoll_ctl");
                      }
                      printf ("Connected: Server: %s\n", hp->h_name);
                      forwardSockets[infd] = forwardSD; //fd_new - новое соеинение (клиент), forwardSD - сокет для транспортировки
                      internalSockets[forwardSD] = infd; // fd_new = infd

                      continue;
                }
                if (!forwardData(events[i].data.fd))
                {
          // epoll will remove the fd from its set
          // automatically when the fd is closed
                    printf("CLOSE EVENTS[i].DATA.FD\n");
                    close (events[i].data.fd);
                }
            }
        }

      free (events);
      close (sfd);

      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    /* Forward data between sockets */
    static int forwardData (int fd)
    {
        //source_sock - fd
        //destination_sock - forwardData

        ssize_t n;

        int forwardData;
        if(forwardSockets[fd] != 0){
            forwardData = forwardSockets[fd];
        }
        if(internalSockets[fd] != 0){
            forwardData = internalSockets[fd];
        }

        char buffer[BUFLEN];
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        while ((n = recv(fd, buffer, BUFLEN, 0)) > 0) { // read data from input socket
                            printf("OK\n");
                            printf("n = %zd\n", n);
                            printf("buffer = %s", buffer);
            send(forwardData, buffer, n, 0); // send data to output socket

            return TRUE;
        }


        printf("------------------buf-------------------------\n");
        printf("------------------end buf---------------------\n");
        /*if (n < 0) {
            exit(-9);
        }*/

        //shutdown(forwardData, SHUT_RDWR); // stop other processes from using socket
        //close(forwardData);

        //shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR); // stop other processes from using socket
        //close(fd);

        return TRUE;

        printf ("I kill fd\n");
    }
```

Ошибка как-то связана с методом `static int forwardData (int fd)`. После небольшого ожидания я вижу в терминале `printf("------------------buf-------------------------\n"); printf("------------------end buf---------------------\n");` эти 2 строки, затем ошибка EPOLLERR и браузер не может отобразить страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно определить, какая именно ошибка (`errno`) произошла на сокете, если epoll вернул EPOLLERR:

```
int error = 0;
socklen_t errlen = sizeof(error);
if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void *)&error, &errlen) == 0)
{
    printf("error = %s\n", strerror(error));
}
```

Без проверки отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150377/how-to-get-errno-when-epoll-wait-returns-epollerr

Comment: спасибо за совет. Добавил код, который Вы написали в ответе. В терминале получаю `error = Success`. Что это значит?

Comment: Это значит ошибок нет. Но у вас проверка (events[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) || (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)), а это значит, что может быть реакция вашего кода на флаг EPOLLHUP, а не EPOLLERR.

Comment: то, что ошибка в EPOLLERR я уверен (код для проверки закомментирован в приведенном мною коде, т.к. нужен был мне для понимания ошибки)

Сейчас в вашем коде вместо "fd" я прописал events[i].data.fd в том куске кода, где происходит проверка на ошибки EPOLLERR, EPOLLHUP и EPOLLIN и получил 
    epoll error
    error = Broken pipe

Comment: я начинаю понимать почему так может происходить (судя по тому, что я нагуглил, мой сокет, то есть дескриптор events[i].data.fd закрывается где-то), но где я его закрываю - не пойму.

Comment: Его закрывает клиент. Возможно. Ну и в getsockopt конечно нужно подставлять нужный сокет, а не любой.

Comment: В моем случае клиент - это браузер. И когда появляется  ошибка "error = Broken pipe", вкладка браузера с моей страницей не загружается до конца, но если я остановлю загрузку страницы в браузере и возобновлю ее, то она загружается и отображается корректно. Я уже голову себе сломал, ничего не понимаю, как это можно решить (((

Comment: Возможно, коннект рвет сервер, на который вы пытаетесь перенаправить запрос.